# Why does decreasing tax rate decreases deferred tax assets?

Tags: united-states, taxes

The was I understand deferred tax assets:

I think I will have `x` profits, but the IRS says that as of today I must pay taxes based on `2x`. So I pay `2x * tax_rate`, giving me `x * tax_rate` deferred tax assets. Now the tax rate drops to  `y < x`, so why do my deferred tax assets drop as well? I would expect them to increase since the IRS has to pay `x * tax_rate` back and also `(x - y) * tax_rate` on top of that.

Why decreasing tax rate decreases deferred tax assets?

Comment: Who told you that your assets became worth less?

Comment: http://uk.businessinsider.com/bank-of-america-fourth-quarter-earnings-q4-2018-1
Like the other big banks, Bank of America took a hit from the recently enacted tax law, writing down $2.9 billion primarily in deferred tax assets that declined in value.

Comment: What country?  (I'm guessing US, but please verify.)

Comment: Yes, US mainly but I would expect this to be similar in other counter under some generally accepted accounting principles perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

A Deferred Tax Asset is a result of something that lowers net income (lowering tax due) but for whatever reason cannot (or chosen to not) be deducted from a tax standpoint until a future period. Thus it will be deductible in *future* periods. *Usually* this is because companies can report certain things (like carried forward losses) on their income statement but not their tax return.

Say a company has a loss of $1,000,000 that for some reason it cannot deduct in 2017, but *can* deduct it in future years.

In 2017, the corporate tax rate is 35%, and the *future* tax benefit (asset) of that loss is $350,000. However in 2018, the tax rate drops to 21%, and the tax benefit of the loss drops to $210,000, for a net *loss* of $140,000.

Your example is a little convoluted (e.g. reducing `x` instead of the tax rate), but it would be more accurate to say " <strike>the IRS has to pay back</strike> Your future deduction is `x * tax_rate_2` instead of `x * tax_rate`." In other words, you don't get a *refund* on prior taxes paid because the rate drops.

Comment: Exactly the correct answer.